# Yaml Values not iterable in python 3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing

In order to update 1000s of Json file  for updating it from a master Yaml file in a automated way. I am facing issue in the for loop during the iteration. I have pyyaml installed using pip and am using python 3.7 version

My yaml file(master_conf.yaml) is below

```
-  sourcesys1:
    sourceServer: 1.2.3.500
    MailTo: gokul@gmail.com
-  sourcesys2:
    sourceServer1: 2.2.3.500
    sourceServer2: 3.2.3.500
    MailTo: gokul@gmail.com
```

My Json files(sourcesys1.json) .. sourcesys1000.json

```
   {
        "source":"sourcesys1",
        "frequency":"daily",
        "sourceServer":"1.2.1.2",
        "hostName":"1.2.1.3",
        "fileFormat":"csv",
        "delimiterType":"semicolon"
    }
```

I am trying to iterate a yaml file and trying to put as dictonary and replace these values to a json file

```
   import yaml

    with open("master_conf.yaml", 'r') as f:
        yaml_config = yaml.safe_load(f)

    for config in yaml_config:
    ...  config.keys()[0]: config[config.keys()[0]]
```

I am getting this error in the for statement

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 2, in 
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable**

need help on the above error

Once this is done I need to iterate over json files  to replace the values in the yaml file

This is the final code where I am facing issue in the yaml file dictionary creation

```
import json
import yaml

with open("mast_conf.yaml", 'r') as f:
    yaml_config = yaml.safe_load(f)

yaml_config = {
    config.keys()[0]: config[config.keys()[0]]
    for config in yaml_config
}

json_files = (
    "sourcesystem1.json",
    "sourcesystem2.json",
)

for json_file in json_files:
    with open(json_file, "r") as f:
        sourcesystem_conf = json.load(f)

    sourcesystem = sourcesystem_conf["source"]

    if sourcesystem in yaml_config:
        for key, value in yaml_config[sourcesystem].items():
            sourcesystem_conf[key] = value

    with open(json_file, "w") as f:
        json.dump(sourcesystem_conf, f, indent=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 .keys() returns an iterable but not indexable object.
Try to convert it into list
to convert the yaml into your example dictionary you can use the library bios

```
import bios

yaml_config = bios.read('master_conf.yaml')
print(yaml_config)
```

this gives you the dictionary format you provided.

Comment: I tried that but i am getting another error , still getting the same errror

Comment: >>> yaml_config = {
...     list(config.keys()[0]): list(config[config.keys()[0]])
...     for config in yaml_config
... }
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <dictcomp>
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable
>>>

Comment: please, provide the example of expected dictionary you want to create from the yaml file.

Comment: yaml_config = 
{'sourcesystem1': {'MailTo': 'gokul@gmail.com', 'sourceServer': '1.2.3.500'},
 'sourcesystem2': {'MailTo': 'gokul@gmail.com',
  'sourceServer1': '2.2.3.500',
  'sourceServer2': '3.2.3.500'}}

Comment: the code is running but the values in json are not getting updated from the yaml file